# Looping through Insert Template in Formview to Obtain Controls Id returns nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a formview with some textboxes. The value of these textboxes need to be encrypted at the time of item inserting before saving into the db table. 
I have been trying the below code with various variations with out any luck. It doent return anything or ends up with object reference null message.

```
    protected void formview1_iteminserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {

 if (FormView1.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Insert)
        {
        foreach (Control c in FormView1.Controls)
        {


            if (c is TextBox)
            {


                TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)c;                
                Response.Write(txtBox.ID);
            }
        } }
```

Comment: Make sure your textboxes aren't in another control in the form. If so, then loop through that control's controls for WinForms. For WPF it may be children or content.

Comment: Maybe its because your textboxes are nested in another controls , so you have to probably use a recursive method

Comment: Thanks you gentlemen for throwing some more light on this.
All i have is this:
form id="form1"  below that is 
asp:Panel ID="panelformview"  and below this is 
asp:FormView ID="FormView1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you could do a trick to achieve this using a loop:

**Remember**

If you have used the VS wizard to populate your `FormView` data control using a `SqlDataSource` then your text-box controls's ID will be look like this: `[Name of Data Field] + TextBox`

> ```
>  //auto generated by VS Wizard
> <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("NameText") %>' ID="NameTextBox" />
> ```

But if you have created them yourself you could still follow this rule to name your control IDs the same as above. and **this is important for our trick**.

Now you could simply use this code to get all of your text-box controls's value.

```
protected void FormView1_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
{            
    foreach (dynamic value in e.Values)
    {
        TextBox txtBox = FormView1.FindControl(value.Key + "TextBox") as TextBox;
        if (txtBox != null)
        {
            Response.Write(txtBox.ID);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note** There won't be any exceptions if the control not found because it will be automatically handled by the `as` operator keyword for you ;-)

Comment: Sounds interesting. I am going to try this out tonight. Thanks!